# Why can't I pass typedef or enum in Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, typedef

The following sketch to fails to compile in the Arduino environment.

Given that [typedefs can be used within Arduino software](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17797290/257), is *Automatic Prototype Generation* the underlying mechanism that causes the failure? If so, what is it and why isn't Arduino providing a lightweight wrapper around C++?

```cpp
#define PRODUCE_WACKY_COMPILETIME_ERROR
typedef int MyMeaningfulType;

#ifndef PRODUCE_WACKY_COMPILETIME_ERROR
void myFunc(MyMeaningfulType myParam);
#endif

void myFunc(MyMeaningfulType myParam)
{
  myFunc(10);
}

void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

For the benefit of the search engines, the errors reported are:

```
error: variable or field 'myFunc' declared void
error: 'MyMeaningfulType' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Great summary of the problem.  I had the same issue.  When I ran a sketch in the context of the library examples, everything worked.  But when I created a new sketch, copied the example sketch and added the library, I got the errors described by the OP.  Declaring the functions at the top of the file or in a separate .h file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please refer to http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess the specific quote is:

```
This means that if you want to use a custom type as a function argument, you should declare it within a separate header file.
```

This page does a good job of explaining how the Arduino Language is different from C/C++ in how it works/pre-processes files.

Answer (score 0):

They are attempting to create prototypes for every function they find. Unfortunately, if you define a typedef in the file before the function, and use that in a function definition, the place they put the function prototype does not see it, and this generates a syntax error.

If you use the 'struct  * ' syntax instead in those function definitions, you benefit from C's 'opaque type' facility, in which you can use a struct definition without having it be declared beforehand. So, build the typedef, use it, but use the struct definition in any functions that use the typedef in arguments.

```
typedef struct mytype_ {
    int f1;
} mytype_t;

void myfunc(struct mytype_ * xxx) {
    xxx->f1 = 1;
}
```