# create a list of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, list, arduino

I am trying to create a list like:

```
[(0, 100), (1, 200), (2, 300), (3, 400), (4, 450), (5, 500), (6, 550), (7, 560), (8, 570)]
```

I made it in python by simply zipping two list;

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [100,200,300,400,450,500,550,560,570]

zipit = zip(x,y)
```

What is the best way to do the same in Arduino C?

Comment: Do you know the max length of that list?

Comment: yes that will be fixed, lets say 100.

Comment: Are these values constants? Because you've just used up 400 Bytes of your memory.

Comment: Is it only the demo data that one obviously does not need it at all, because x[i] == i ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use struct that holds 2 `int`s and make an array out of it:

```
struct pair {int a; int b;} arr[100];
void setup() {
  //creating simple [(5,6), (1,2)]
 arr[0].a = 5;
 arr[0].b = 6;

 arr[1].a = 1;
 arr[1].b = 2;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use structures.

```
struct List{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and then

```
struct List list[100] = { {0, 100}, {1, 200}, {2, 300} 
                   // Rest of the initialization
                 };
```

Comment: you can't use `typedef` in Arduino

Comment: @ThunderWiring some say so some say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796344/custom-enum-type-declaration-with-arduino/17797290#17797290